# Performance loss due to add asp.net_isapi to request pipeline?

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis-6, url-rewriting, isapi

is there a notable performance loss if all files are handled with the aspnet_isapi in request pipeline using IIS6? IIS7 has the new integrated pipeline so that seems not to be a problem.

I ask this, because I want apply an .net url replacer on .exe files for example. To do so, I have to add them to the asp.net isapi. I fear this could slow down the IIS/Website.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two posts should help you decide:

> [IIS 6.0 wildcard mapping benchmarks? (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323325/iis-6-0-wildcard-mapping-benchmarks)
>   [ASP.net MVC performance with extensionless url on IIS 6 (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522286/asp-net-mvc-performance-with-extensionless-url-on-iis-6)

This answer explains how the ASP.NET pipeline handles static files:

> [ASP.net MVC performance with extensionless url on IIS 6 - Answer (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522286/asp-net-mvc-performance-with-extensionless-url-on-iis-6/1522326#1522326)